# TBB Parallel_for count, increment variable inaccurate

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, tbb

I am aware that with parallel processes, without proper care you can get race conditions where one thread modifies a variable that another is accessing, causing various errors and such.

I am trying to write code that makes use of a 'parallel_for', a global variable 'count' and a condition to increment 'count'.

once the condition is met, I call count++ from inside the parallel for.

for data validation I setup a parallel_reduce that also checks for the same condition and I receive a different result, which is higher than what I get with the parallel_for, which is why I know that the parallel_for is causing the issue.

Am I right in thinking that using 'count++' is still causing a race condition, as my original assumption was that count++ would work as i'm never storing a value, just at the point in time, saying just add 1 to whatever 'count' is.
I want to try and avoid using mutex or locks if possible.

```
int count = 0;

parallel_for(blocked_range2d<int, int>(0, smallestHeight, 0, smallestWidth), [&](const blocked_range2d<int, int>&r) {
        auto y1 = r.rows().begin();
        auto y2 = r.rows().end();
        auto x1 = r.cols().begin();
        auto x2 = r.cols().end();

        for (auto y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
            for (auto x = x1; x < x2; x++) {

                int pixelValue = rgbDiffVal[y][x].rgbRed + rgbDiffVal[y][x].rgbGreen + rgbDiffVal[y][x].rgbBlue;

                if (pixelValue > bThreshold) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: Yes, increment (++) causes a race condition. In order to avoid it, declare the variable atomic. And it's not `parallel_for` causing the issue but the race in your code.

Comment: Its more of a theory question so I didn't think the code was relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tbb::parallel_for` assumes that the body of the loop is thread-safe, i.e. does not have races. In this case, it does have a race, as it modifies a global variable without synchronization. The fact that modification is a mere increment of "whatever the current value is" does not matter, it is still a race (for example, some hardware might implement ++ as reading a value from memory to register, changing the register, writing new value back to memory).

In order to fix this code, declare `count` as an atomic variable: `std::atomic<int>` if you use C++11, or `tbb::atomic<int>` for earlier versions of the language.

Comment: Is this better or worse than using a mutex?

Comment: Acquiring a mutex typically means one atomic operation, as threads need to modify the mutex state atomically. So for a single increment, atomic operation is likely more efficient than using a mutex.
But generally, do not make assumptions about performance; measure and make decisions based on data.